# Unable to install JSON ruby gem on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, ubuntu, rubygems

I require the json ruby gem to test some JSON files in Rspec. I use bundler to manage my gems, with my Gemfile looking as such:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rake'
gem 'rspec'
gem 'json', '1.8.2'
```

However when I run bundle install everything passes but the json gem. Of which I get the following error message:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in 'require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in 'require'
    from extconf.rb:1:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.2/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing json (1.8.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that 'gem install json -v '1.8.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I've already looked around and seen this suggestion:

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev
```

I've done this but the error is still present. The gem version I'm trying to install is `1.8.2`, my ruby version is `ruby 1.9.3p484` as this is the last stable release for Ubuntu 14.04 as far as I'm aware

If anyone could help resolve this I'd be very grateful

Comment: “`ruby` version is ruby 1.9.3p484 as this is the last stable release for Ubuntu 14.04 as far as I'm aware”—nobody uses ruby from Ubuntu repositories. Consider using either [`rvm`](http://rvm.io/) or [`rbenv`](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) or [`chruby`](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby). `1.9.3` is a not-supported anymore legacy.

Comment: Try installing `libpq-dev and build-essential`. `sudo apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev`.

Comment: While its true that using a version manager is a good idea in case you ever want to install a second version in the future, you could probably get a newer version of ruby through apt-get. You could check if the `ruby2.3` and `ruby2.3-dev` packages are available. You could also download a binary from [here](https://rvm.io/binaries/). However this doesn't necessarily solve the json issue. Try removing the `, '1.8.2'` part and see if that works.